# Select week from MySQL database where the week runs from Wednesday to Tuesday

Tags: php, mysql

I have a perfectly running program which grabs information from my database on a weekly basis.  My current problem is that now I have to change the program from selecting the current week (Sunday to Saturday) to selecting the week starting on Wednesday through Tuesday.

Here is the query I have now which runs fine for Sunday through Saturday:

```
SELECT time, roNum
FROM $user 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method for doing this is to adjust the date before extracting the date components.  In this case, you can probably subtract two days before extracting the year and week:

```
SELECT time, roNum
FROM $user
WHERE YEAR(date - interval 2 day) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
      WEEK(date - interval 2 day) = WEEK(CURDATE());
```

Comment: Didn't work, still only showing week beginning Sunday and ending Saturday.  If I add an entry for last Thursday, it does not pull it out in my program.  If I change the date to Today, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gordon Linoff for getting me on the right track.  Your answer helped me to figure it out.  Here is the code that got me to where I needed to be:

```
SELECT time, roNum
FROM $user
WHERE YEAR(date + interval 4 day) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
      WEEK(date + interval 4 day) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```